# What is the max addressable memory space in a 32-bit C++ program?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

In debug mode I saw that the pointers have addresses like 0x01210040,
but as I realized, 0x means hexadecimal right? And there're 8 hex digits, i.e. in total there're are 128 bits that are addressed?? So does that mean that for 32-bit system the first two digits are always 0, and for a 64-bit system the first digit is 0?

Also, may I ask that, for a 32-bit program, would I be able to allocate as much as 3GB of memory as long as I remain in the heap and use only malloc()? Or is there some limitations the Windows system poses on a single thread? (the IDE I'm using is VS2012)

Since actually I was running a 32-bit program in a 64-bit system, but the program crashed with a memory leak when it only allocated about 1.5GB of memory...and I can't seem to figure out why.

(Oooops...sorry guys I think I made a simple mistake with the first question...indeed one hex digit is 4 bits, and 8 makes 32bits. However here is another question...how is address represented in a 64-bit program?)

Comment: 2^32 bytes = 4294967296B = 4GB

Comment: Each hex digit is 4 bits, so 8 hex digits == 32 bits...

Comment: arrrgh!!That's right...why did I just have the crazy idea that each hex digit is two bytes...

Comment: What exactly are you asking? In a 32-bit program an address is a 32-bit value. In a 64-bit program an address is a 64-bit value (although [only the low 48 bits are used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Virtual_address_space_details)). The hexadecimal representation is just used to display an address to humans, like all numbers they are represented in binary (that's what _bit_ means)

Comment: In a linear address space, the possible address space is 4GB.  One note is that many hardware items are memory mapped to addresses.  So your program may not be able to address the entire range.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For 32-bit Windows, the limit is actually 2GB usable per process, with virtual addresses from `0x00000000` (or simply `0x0`) through `0x7FFFFFFF`. The rest of the 4GB address space (`0x80000000` through `0xFFFFFFFF`) for use by Windows itself. Note that these have nothing to do with the actual physical memory addresses.

If your program is large address space aware, this limit is increased to 3GB on 32bit systems and 4GB for 32bit programs running on 64bit Windows.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366912(v=vs.85).aspx

And for the higher limits for large address space aware programs (`IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE`), see here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx

You might also want to take a look at the [Virtual Memory article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) to better understand how the mapping between virtual addresses and physical addresses works. The first MSDN link above also has a short explanation:

> The virtual address space for a process is the set of virtual memory
>   addresses that it can use. The address space for each process is
>   private and cannot be accessed by other processes unless it is shared.
>   A virtual address does not represent the actual physical location of
>   an object in memory; instead, the system maintains a page table for
>   each process, which is an internal data structure used to translate
>   virtual addresses into their corresponding physical addresses. Each
>   time a thread references an address, the system translates the virtual
>   address to a physical address. The virtual address space for 32-bit
>   Windows is 4 gigabytes (GB) in size and divided into two partitions:
>   one for use by the process and the other reserved for use by the
>   system. For more information about the virtual address space in 64-bit
>   Windows, see [Virtual Address Space in 64-bit Windows.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384271(v=vs.85).aspx)

---

**EDIT:** As [user3344003 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25165393/202504), these values are *not* the amount of memory you can allocate using malloc or otherwise use for storing values, they just represent the size of the virtual address space.

Comment: thanks! But actually my system is 64bit, and I haven't declared the 2GB limit as described in MSDN...but the program itself is inherently 32-bit so I guess I can use 4GB most (or is it 32bit?? How would one check if a program is 64bit or not?)

Comment: Check your settings in Visual Studio, there you can change the build architecture to either 32bit or 64bit. If you are still unsure, use the `dumpbin` tool as described [here](http://superuser.com/a/358459/59125)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of limits that would restrict the size of your malloc allocation.

1) The number of bits, restricts the size of the address space. For 32-bits, that is 4B.
2) System the subdivide that for the various processor modes. These days, usually 2GB goes to the user and 2GB to the kernel.
3) The address space may be limited by the size of the page tables.
4) The total virtual memory may be limited by the size of the page file.
5) Before you start malloc'ing, there be stuff already in the virtual address space (e.g., code stack, reserved area, data). Your malloc needs to return a contiguous block of memory. Largest theoretical block it could return has to fit within unallocated areas of virtual memory.
6) Your memory management heap may restrict the size that can be allocated.

There probably other limitations that I have omitted.

-=-=-=-=-

If your program crashed after allocating 1.5GB through malloc, did you check the return value from malloc to see if it was not null?

-=-=-=-=-=

The best way to allocate huge blocks of memory is through operating system services to map pages into the virtual address space.---not using malloc.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to the following [article](http://www.viva64.com/en/k/0036/)

For a 32-bit application launched in a 32-bit Windows, the total size of all the mentioned data types must not exceed 2 Gbytes. 
The same 32-bit program launched in a 64-bit system can allocate about 4 Gbytes (actually about 3.5 Gbytes)

The practical data you are looking at is around 1.7 GB due to space occupied by windows.

By any chance how did you find out the memory it had allocated when it crashed.?

Comment: yes...32bit program in 64bit windows, I was checking the task manager and saw the thread take up more and more memory until it crashes at 1.5